# In Excel, the class does not appear as desired, but as object + number

Tags: python, csv

```
from BBlineup import Player

import csv

FILENAME = "baseball.csv"

def write_players(players):
    with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(players)

def read_players():
    players = []
    with open(FILENAME, 'r', newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            players.append(row)
    return players

#---------------------------------------------------------------

def add_player(players):    
    f_name = input("First name: ").title()
    l_name = input("Last name: ")    
    position = get_player_position()
    at_bats = get_at_bats()
    hits = get_hits(at_bats)
    avg = get_batting_avg(at_bats, hits)
    
    player = Player(f_name, l_name, position, at_bats, hits, avg)

    players.append(player)
    print(f"{player.f_name} {player.l_name} was added.\n")
    write_players(players)
    
def get_player_position():
    while True:
        position = input("Position: ").upper()
        if position in POSITIONS:
            return position
        else:
            print("Invalid position. Try again.")
            display_positions()

def get_at_bats():
    while True:
        at_bats = int(input("At bats: "))
        if at_bats < 0 or at_bats > 10000:    
            print("Invalid entry. Must be from 0 to 10,000.")
        else:
            return at_bats

def get_hits(at_bats):
    while True:
        hits = int(input("Hits: "))
        if hits < 0 or hits > at_bats:
            print(f"Invalid entry. Must be from 0 to {at_bats}.")
        else:
            return hits
        
def get_batting_avg(at_bats, hits):
    avg = hits / at_bats
    return round(avg, 3)

def display_positions():
    print("POSITIONS")
    print("C, 1B, 2B, 3B, SS, LF, CF, RF, P")

def delete_player(players):
    number = get_lineup_number(players, "Number: ")
    player = players.pop(number-1)

    print(f"{player.f_name} {player.l_name} was deleted.\n")
    write_players(players)
    
def move_player(players):
    old_number = get_lineup_number(players, "Current lineup number: ")
    print(f"{players[old_number-1].f_name} {players[old_number-1].l_name} was selected.")
    new_number = get_lineup_number(players, "New lineup number: ")
    
    player = players.pop(old_number-1)
    players.insert(new_number-1, player)
    print(f"{player.f_name} {player.l_name} was moved.\n")

def edit_player_position(players):
    number = get_lineup_number(players, "Lineup number: ")
    player = players[number-1]
    print(f"You selected {player.f_name} {player.l_name} POS={player.position}")
    
    position = get_player_position()
    player.position = position
    print(f"{player.f_name} {player.l_name} was updated.\n")

def edit_player_stats(players):
    number = get_lineup_number(players, "Lineup number: ")
    player = players[number-1]
    print(f"You selected {player.f_name} {player.l_name} AB={player.at_bats} H={player.hits}")
    
    at_bats = get_at_bats()
    hits = get_hits(at_bats)
    player.at_bats = at_bats
    player.hits = hits
    print(f"{player.f_name} {player.l_name} was updated.\n")

def display_lineup(players):
    if players == None:
        print("There are currently no players in the lineup.")        
    else:
        print(" Player\t\tPOS\tAB\tH\tAVG")
        print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
        for i, player in enumerate(players, start=1):
            
            print(f"{i} {player.f_name} {player.l_name}\t\t{player.position}\t{player.at_bats}\t{player.hits}\t{player.avg}")
    print()

def get_lineup_number(players, prompt):
    while True:
        number = int(input(prompt))
        if number < 1 or number > len(players):
            print("Invalid player number. Please try again.")
        else:
            return number

def display_separator():
    print("=======================================================")

def display_title():
    print("                   Baseball Team Manager")

def display_menu():
    print("MENU OPTIONS")
    print("1 – Display lineup")
    print("2 – Add player")
    print("3 – Remove player")
    print("4 – Move player")
    print("5 – Edit player position")
    print("6 – Edit player stats")
    print("7 - Exit program")
    print()

def display_positions():
    print("POSITIONS")
    print("C, 1B, 2B, 3B, SS, LF, CF, RF, P")

POSITIONS = ("C", "1B", "2B", "3B", "SS", "LF", "CF", "RF", "P")

def main():
    display_separator()
    display_title()
    display_menu()
    display_positions()
    display_separator()

    players = read_players()

    players = []
    while True:
        option = int(input("Menu option: "))
        if option == 1:
            display_lineup(players)
        elif option == 2:
            add_player(players)
        elif option == 3:
            delete_player(players)
        elif option == 4:
            move_player(players)
        elif option == 5:
            edit_player_position(players)
        elif option == 6:
            edit_player_stats(players)
        elif option == 7:
            print("Bye!")
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid option. Please try again.\n")
            display_menu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self,f_name, l_name, position, at_bats, hits,avg):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.position = position
        self.at_bats = at_bats
        self.hits = hits
        self.avg = avg
```

When the class is added to the csv file and the csv file is opened, <BBlineup.Player object at 0x000002337BB870D0> these values appear.
The class is created in another window. It seems to be an error while sending information to the csv file. I want to solve this.
Please tell me how to make the value I registered enter into excel

Comment: 1) CSV != Excel,  and I don't see where Excel is involved in this. 2) Make this a minimal test case, we don't need to see the whole project, just how the data is saved to the file and what `Player` is. 3) This, `player = Player(f_name, l_name, position, at_bats, hits, avg)` is your problem, CSV is a text format it knows nothing about Python objects. What you are getting is basically `player.__repr__()` or a textual description of the object. If you want to save the data just use `f_name, l_name, position, at_bats, hits, avg`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: OP is using Excel as a csv file viewer.